# Columns in PdfPTable

Tags: java, pdf, jdbc, itext, actionlistener

I need help with the columns in the table to hide them and show up in the table when the radio button is clicked. My application should generate reports from the jdbc database, but the columns in PdfPtable should be optional. For example, if I have columns in the database: Name, Surname, Date .... If the Name radio button is selected The Name column will be displayed in the Pdf report. If you click on the radio button Surname in pdf report, a new Surname column is displayed. Conversely, if the column is clicked away, it will disappear.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.. Please read guidelines on how to ask a question on stackoverflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That is not what pdf is meant for. You can try and emulate something like that using optional content groups but it's complicated and a mere work-around.